# iphone dev: UIImageview subclass interface builder - how to call custom initializer

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, initialization, subclass

I messing with iphone developement.  I have a uiimageview subclass that I want to use to detect touches.  I have sucessfully added to interfacebuilder and I can detect a touch in my UIImageview subclass within my application so all is good on that front.  however my UIImageView subclass has a custom initializer which is not called when it is created in interface builder.

if I manually initialize the UIImageview and add it programmatically I think it will work but then I lose the ability to 'see' my positioning in Interface builder.

how can I either

1) 'see' a uiimageview in interface builder that is added in code? (not possible?)
2) call my custom initializer when the subclass is instantiated in interfacebuilder.

thanks

---

Hi thanks for suggestions.  I think I'm getting closer to understanding the relationship between the xib and the viewcontroller.

I now am sucessfully adding my UIImageView subclass programmatically and using my custom initiializer which overrides InitWithFrame.

I think I read that the xib calls 'awakeFromNib' so I could equally add my iniitialization code in there.  I like the idea of adding it programmatically as I have more control (although harderto set up my IU)

so one more realted question.  if I add an UIImageView subclass in interface builder.  I can see it and detect touches on it.  if I want to refer to it in the view controller class do I have a pointer to it?  i.e. is there a variable name for it?  the UIImageViews I create myself I obviuosly know what they are called.....

Comment: Have you found an answer? Please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You likely have put your instructions in the wrong initializer.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html), objects unarchived from a NIB are initialized with `initWithCode:` if they conform to the `NSCoding` protocol; objects that don't conform to  `NSCoding` are initialized with `init`.

In this particular case, UIImageView does conform to `NSCoding`. It's likely that you have you intended for `initWithFrame:` to be called and put your instructions in that method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply put your initialisation logic in viewDidLoad? In particular,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Put whatever was in your custom initialiser here.
}
```

Comment: Depending on the needs of ninjasmith, this may be the better route. If it's a one time use, your solution is probably ideal. If he's looking for reusability, making a class with the right initializer may be preferable.